# Invalid operation while gcnew Image CLI/C++

Tags: c++, image, dll, command-line-interface

I get weird information about `invalidOperationException` in `PresentationCore.dll` while constructing an image by `gcnew Image()`.

I attach project and the JPG file (which can be put in `C:\`) It actually cannot be checked other way because configuration of project (references) took a long time, and just copied code will not work.

http://www.speedyshare.com/Vrr84/Jpg.zip

How can I solve that problem?

[image]

---

```
 // Jpg.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
    //

#include "stdafx.h"
#using <mscorlib.dll> //requires CLI
using namespace System;
using namespace System::IO;
using namespace System::Windows::Media::Imaging;
using namespace System::Windows::Media;
using namespace System::Windows::Controls;
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{


    // Open a Stream and decode a JPEG image
        Stream^ imageStreamSource = gcnew FileStream("C:/heart.jpg", FileMode::Open, FileAccess::Read, FileShare::Read);
        
        JpegBitmapDecoder^ decoder = gcnew JpegBitmapDecoder(imageStreamSource, BitmapCreateOptions::PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption::Default);
        BitmapSource^ bitmapSource = decoder->Frames[0];//< --mamy bitmape
    
        // Draw the Image
        Image^ myImage = gcnew Image();//<----------- ERROR
        myImage->Source = bitmapSource;
        myImage->Stretch = Stretch::None;
        myImage->Margin = System::Windows::Thickness(20);
        //

        int width = 128;
        int height = width;
        int stride = width / 8;
        array<System::Byte>^ pixels = gcnew array<System::Byte>(height * stride);

        // Define the image paletteo
        BitmapPalette^ myPalette = BitmapPalettes::Halftone256;

        // Creates a new empty image with the pre-defined palette.
        BitmapSource^ image = BitmapSource::Create(
           width, height,
           96, 96,
           PixelFormats::Indexed1,
           myPalette,
           pixels,
           stride);

        System::IO::FileStream^ stream = gcnew System::IO::FileStream("new.jpg", FileMode::Create);
        JpegBitmapEncoder^ encoder = gcnew JpegBitmapEncoder();
        TextBlock^ myTextBlock = gcnew System::Windows::Controls::TextBlock();
        myTextBlock->Text = "Codec Author is: " + encoder->CodecInfo->Author->ToString();
        encoder->FlipHorizontal = true;
        encoder->FlipVertical = false;
        encoder->QualityLevel = 30;
        encoder->Rotation = Rotation::Rotate90;
        encoder->Frames->Add(BitmapFrame::Create(image));
        encoder->Save(stream);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The Image class is not what you think it is.  It is a *control*, it belongs in a Window.  Which is why it barks at you about the apartment state.  Same is true for TextBlock, it won't do what you hope it does.  WPF isn't exactly ideal for image processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The core issue is there:

> The calling thread must be STA [...]

Your main thread must be marked as a *single-threaded apartment* (STA for short) for WPF to function correctly. The fix? Add `[System::STAThread]` to your `_tmain`, thus informing the runtime that the main thead has to be STA.

```
[System::STAThread]
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    // the rest of your code doesn't change
}
```